# Data not loading using input lookup in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
<aura:application access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" default="" access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objNew" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType':'Contact',  
                                                       'Id':null}" />
    <div class="well">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Search Team Events</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal" >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <c:inputLookup type="Contact"
                                         value="{!v.Id}"
                                         className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <c:testCal />
</aura:application>
```

I am using these resouces https://github.com/enreeco/inputlookup

Answer (score 0):

have you triged installing the unmanaged package provided?
Do you see any error in the JS console?
I think it is releated to the last platform releases and the component stopped working properly.
I'll get an eye as soon as I can!

**UPDATE**

I have tested the component installing the package in a new Dev ORG and it worked.

I have My Domain enabled and access the example app with https://mydomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/InputLookupExample.app

Did you install the unmanaged package provided?

You can install it with from https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t24000000TxtD

Comment: Are you using the "c" namespace or a custom one?

Comment: If the code is available there, then could you tell me why installing requried ?

Comment: @EnricoMurru thanks Murru but i did not install this package yet, I just pull the code from Github repo. And the code is not working properly.

Comment: @EnricoMurru...I saw your above link..it works properly...

Comment: I think there is a misallineament between github repo and the package. I'll check it ouy.